# Base 64 in preview chrome-devtools. How fix?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Today chrome updated to version 70, and this i saw in tab Preview
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSps8.png)
It's format base64, but if you open Response you will see JSON 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsXq7.png)
How I can return normal preview, this is very uncomfortable, i use other resources just for see what i got?